# PHP Posting a Link to Facebook as Page not as User

Tags: php, facebook

Im using the below code to post to messages to fanpages:

```
$message = "test";
$link = "http://test.com";
$pageid = "123456789";
$post_url = '/'.$pageid.'/feed';
$msg_body = array(
'message' => $message,
if ($fbuser) {
try {
$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}else{
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
}
```

and is working fine (is posting as fanpage name), but If i change:

```
'message' => $message,
```

to

```
'link' => $link,
```

is posting as my username not as fanpage, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get access token granted for this page, and use it while posting:

```
$accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
foreach($accounts['data'] as $account){
   if($account['id'] == $pageid){
      $token = $account['access_token'];
   }
}
$msg_body = array(
    'link' => $link,
    'access_token' => $token
);
$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body);
```

Comment: to my code I just changed /feed with /links and is posting fine, but seems after 2 hours token is expiring, im trying to post on 3 pages on same time, so if I use your code to get the token for pageid1 will that token works for other pages too or I need to take a token for each page? thanks.

Comment: every page has it's own access token, IIRC using invalid token will result in posting as your account, not as page.